# Binding REST API to a new language

Tags: rest-api

Does Salesforce support binding the API to a new language?

What I have learned I need to use the REST API.

How much work would it be? And, what is the attitude of Salesforce towards such community projects?

Comment: A benefit of REST APIs using simple formats like JSON is that any language that has support for making HTTPS calls can use the API.

Comment: We love such community projects. What language are you using?

Comment: Standard ML, a functional language with static typing.